# Why is every Archimedean ordered skew-field necessarily a field?

Tags: field-theory

While browsing around, I read that any ordered skew-field that satisfies the Archimedean property is commutative, but it was offered without proof. Out of curiosity, is there a quick proof or reference for this fact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This goes back to Hilbert. Here's his proof from Section 32 of *Foundations of Geometry*, 1902.

[image]
[image]
[image]